# Trying to change the height of cell contains pickerview when tapping it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I am trying to make cell containing UIPickerView expand when tapped to show more area from my PickerView by changing the cell's height and go back to normal size after the picker selection is done.

When i am tapping the cell only the PickerView inside it is tapped .. so i was unable to use HeightForRow to change the cell height.Can anyone can help !

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

       if (indexPath == [0,0])
        {
             return 150
        }else{
              return 70 
        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `picker.userInteractionEnabled = false`, the tap event will be sent to the cell.  You would then need to reload the table at that index path (to resize the cell), and re-enable the picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use delegate

```
protocol HeightManager{
    func changeHeight(TableCustomCell)
}

class TableCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: HeightManager?

    @IBAction func expandCollapseClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.changeHeight(sender:self)
    }
}
```

in the VC

```
class viewController: UIViewController,HeightManager{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = areaSettTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier1) as! TableCustomCell

         cell.delegate = self

         return cell
    }

    func changeHeight(sender:TableCustomCell) {

      // change height here in say array of heights
       self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```